# What is the shortcut for the little auto suggest blue bar in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, intellisense

In Visual Studio, when you type in a Class name or property that Intellisense doesnt recognise a little blue bar show up underneath the first letter of the word with options like suggestion the namespace to import and refactor etc.

Does anyone know the shortcut to open that window with having to mouse over it? I can't for the life of me find it on Google, probably because I can't find out what the function is called.

Comment: The little blue bar is called a 'statement context menu' according to Microsoft's Jeff Widmer. Source : http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/use-ctrl-period-to-trigger-visual-studio-s-automatic-add-using-statement-context-menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the Ctrl + . (period) shortcut to open that menu when the blue bar is showing.

Answer (score 1):

Press Alt + Shift + F10 to bring up the context menu.

The commands in this menu are also available in Edit + IntelliSense + Generate.  Only the Generate Method has a predefined shortcut key: Ctrl+K, M.  You could use Tools + Options, Customize, Keyboard to assign additional ones.